# How to get more daily views?

Tags: discussion, beta, area-51, site-promotion

The weakest point on the [Area 51 Site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants) is our views. We need to get **a lot** more if the site wants to leave beta.

But, how can we do this? As it says:

> Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

Currently, we are not getting many search engine traffic **because we are in beta**, so how can we improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are [not indexed](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aproofassistants.stackexchange.com) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oivuf.png)) in Google yet but user LarrySnyder610, moderator of our [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com) site, obtained excellent results from posting on his Twitter account.

There was a discussion in the [Operations Research chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/94323?m=50525498#50525498) about promoting that site in its early days; using Tweets seemed to be the most productive, but he has an established account and a good following.

> "In terms of promotion: I've been posting frequently on Twitter and linked in about it (esp. during commitment phase); added a graphic and link to my email signature; emailed many many colleagues about it; announced to my students and encouraged them to announce to their various listservs, FB groups; announced to an OR & analytics company that I work part-time for; etc.
> I hope others are doing similar things.
> I def. see lots of discussion about it on Twitter.".

A ready-made source of advertising material is our list of "top new questions this week", available in the form of our [Community Digest](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/digest/preview) (which is generated automatically, but [unlisted](https://stackexchange.com/digests) for new sites). Users can post a link to that URL on their Twitter feed and the contents are updated automatically each week.

Answer (score 2):

The daily views statistics have nothing to do with whether or not a site leaves Beta.

We will leave Beta eventually. You just have to be patient.

Once we leave Private Beta, views will increase as we qualify for HNQ.